# polygon shading when editing

Tags: shaders

Just starting out, wondering exactly what the darker shading means:

Is it simply shadowing based on the current dimensions?

Is it also an indicator that front and side rigging are somehow not correspondent with each other?

Thanks a bunch.

[image]

Comment: you probably need to recalculate the normals: select all and ctrl N

Answer (score 0):

In edit mode, select your entire mesh and press Ctrl+N. This should recalculate all of the normals and the shading should be correct again.